# Filling Word forms using Access isn't always working

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, form-fields

I'm using a code i found online to fill in form fields in a Word document. When i use it on an empty document and add to it a form field, it works. However, when i use it on the form i'm trying to fill nothing happens when i execute the code. I checked the name of the fields in Word and they match the code, i don't know what's wrong.
  I also checked the data type in Access and it's not the problem, i don't have access to the code right now but does anyone have any idea of what's causing this?
  Edit: Here is a similar code, i don't have access to the exact same one:

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.
Err.Clear
'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.
Set appWord = New Word.Application
End If
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Form.doc", , True)
With doc

.FormFields("TextEn").Result = DLookup("[End date]", "[Table1]", "[Table1]![ID Number] =" & [ID2])
.FormFields("TextSt").Result = DLookup("[Starting date]", "[Table1]", "[Table1]![ID Number] =" & [ID2])



.Visible = True
.Activate
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
```

Comment: Word has a couple different types of fields, so odds are the code is looking for them in the wrong place.  However, it's impossible to tell without seeing the code.  Can you share it?

Comment: i edited the post with the code

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` will hide the true nature of the problem and cause things to fail silently. Try commenting it out.

Comment: I've edited the code, the error i'm getting right now is "Invalid use of Null" pointing to the line with the .FormFields...

Comment: anyone got any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to validate that your dlookup is returning a value with the following:

```
If DCount("[End date]", "[Table1]", "[Table1]![ID Number] =" & [ID2]) > 0 then
  .FormFields("TextEn").Result = DLookup("[End date]", "[Table1]", "[Table1]![ID Number] =" & [ID2])
End If
```

You would have to do this for each lookup before trying to set your fields.